# Is there any way to turn back 'GitHub Bootcamp' bar on main github page?

Tags: github, octopus

I've closed a bar on the main GitHub's page that presented below:

[Bar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDxu.png)

Is there a way to turn it back? :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you remove any cookies it may come back, but this bar is also visible on this the help site - https://help.github.com/